# Best way to interact Amazon S3 bucket programatically AWSSDK for .net or tntDrive?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using AWSSDK for .net to interact with my amazon s3 account bucket.
now I found **tntDrive** that mount that bucket as a local drive to interact with same s3 bucket.
tell me the best way to interact to Amazon S3 bucket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon S3 is an object store, not a filesystem. It is not advisable to mount an Amazon S3 bucket as a drive or filesystem.

For example, on a normal disk filesystem, it is possible to modify a single byte in a file. However, when modifying a single byte in an S3 object, the whole object has to be re-sent to S3.

Utilities that mount an S3 bucket on a filesystem (eg [s3fs](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon), [tntdrive](http://tntdrive.com/), [Cloudberry Drive](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-cloud-storage-online-hard-drive.aspx)) are simulating a filesystem, and have to do a lot of work in the background to remain compatible. It might work and it might make things appear simpler, but it also adds an additional level of complexity that can cause problems to your system. **If you are intending to run a highly-reliable production system, it is advisable not to use such utilities** -- but the choice is yours.

The [AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/) provides many functions for accessing Amazon S3, with full control over security and detailed error codes if things fail. Using a mounted drive has less security (defined when the drive is mounted, rather than for each call to S3) and will not return S3-specific error messages if things fail.

An in-between option you might consider is the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (available for Windows, Mac, Linux). It provides a command-line interface to interact with AWS. One very useful feature is the `aws s3 sync` command, which can synchronize files between a local directory and S3.